# Extract only id object to a new object

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

How can I only take the id when I create a new array?

In the example below, my Permission object has a variable "id", that is all I need when I create my array.  I don't need the other properties of Permission, they should be null in the new array.

```
@Override
public List<Permission> extractPermissionsToId(Role role) {
    List<Permission> unextracted = role.getPermissions();
    List<Permission> extracted = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Permission permission : unextracted) {
        extracted.addAll(permission.getId());
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question here?  you're calling `getId()`, you must know if you can call it - otherwise it wouldn't compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would be comfortable with creating new `Permission` objects for your extracted list, then you may try something along the lines of the following:

```
for (Permission permission : unextracted) {
    Permission p = new Permission();
    p.setId(permission.getId());
    extracted.add(p);
}
```

In other words, you can try creating a new `Permission` object based off the unextracted one, setting only the `id` field.